# Removing unrelated object causes binding loop warnings

Tags: qt, binding, qml, qtquick2

It's been several times already, so this time I decided to ask and see if anyone has an idea what is going on.

I have this item backbone:

```
Item {
  id: main
  property alias rw: main.childrenRect.width
  property alias rh: main.childrenRect.height
  property alias rx: main.childrenRect.x
  property alias ry: main.childrenRect.y

  // other stuff here

  Item {
    Rectangle { // debugrect
      width: main.rw
      height: main.rh
      x: main.rx
      y: main.ry
      color: "#00000000"
    }
  }
}
```

The `debugrect` served as a visual debug aid, note how it is wrapped in another item at position 0,0 with size 0,0 - that is it is not in any way included in the `childrenRect` of the main item. Also it doesn't have an id, thus it is not being referenced by any other item whatsoever.

What's most confusing, it is not the presence of this object that causes binding loop messages, but its removal from the code. For some reason, even though it is completely isolated from influencing any other object, removing it causes binding loops in other objects which have absolutely nothing to do with it. What possible mechanic could involve that isolated object's presence in the manifestation of binding loops?

Note: I have not included the full code because it is irrelevant. It is longer than anyone would be willing to debug for me, I have debugged it and found nothing wrong with it, the question is not about "what's wrong with my code" but about "what's wrong with qt" - about how something isolated could be influencing unrelated bindings or triggering false warnings.

Edit: To dispel theories that the `debugrect` might in some way influence the `main.childrenRect`, I'd like to offer this:

Logical proof: The `debugrect` is sized by the `main.childrenRect`, thus if it influenced it in any way, then **that** would cause a binding loop. There is no such loop, as there is no such influence. The wrapping `Item` does influence the `main.childrenRect`, however, it is a zero size item at position 0,0, and it doesn't move or anything like it, so with or without it, absent any other objects, you'd get a 0,0,0,0 for the `main.childrenRect`.

Practical proof:

```
  Item {
    Rectangle {
      width: 10
      height: 10
    }
    Item {
      Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
      }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(childrenRect)
  }
```

The output, as expected, says: `QRectF(0, 0, 10, 10)` - the inner rectangle does not influence the outer rectangle's `childrenRect` in any way when it is wrapped in a "null" item.

Also, not that it matters, but the binding loops I am getting are about objects, declared in other sources which have no notion of the `debugrect` whatsoever.

My preliminary theory is that the presence or absence of the rectangle in question influences in some way the order and structure of the binding evaluation trees (and not the actual results). The code *is very complex* but it also works just fine, there is no erroneous behavior when the `debugrect` is removed, debugging has not indicated any actual binding loops taking place, just the warnings of them. Big whoop, some might say, however this application redirects the console output to the user to indicate *actual problems* and I can't have it flooded by bogus warnings. As the binding logic is quite complex, it seems to hit a weak spot in the binding evaluation implementation, and from earlier detailed tests I have verified that qml bindings are hardly evaluated in the most logical or efficient way. The solution is to simply leave the rectangle there, but out of curiosity, I would like to get to the bottom of this.

Edit 2: Extra info:

- `debugrect` having static position and dimension results in the same behavior as removing it altogether. It seems that absent those bindings the qtquick runtime generates the warnings
- the `main.childrenRect` is actually barely used. It is not being used to anchor anything, and besides the `debugrect` the only other reference to that, which is the actual intended use, is to size the content size of a `Flickable` the main item is in, and to compensate for objects in negative space, since flickable doesn't seem to work with objects in it, it starts at 0,0. The idea here is for the main item to expand the flickable content area to accommodate all of the main item's children. Removing the intended use reference doesn't make a difference
- the `main.childrenRect` is not used in any way in any of the objects which generate binding loop warnings, neither directly, nor indirectly. What's more, the objects in question don't influence the `main.childrenRect` either

Comment: I loaded your backbone code using QtQuick 2.7 in a default `QQuickView` on Qt 5.7.0 on Windows 10. I did not get any binding loops when I removed the `Rectangle`, and I did not get any binding loops when I removed the inner `Item`.

Comment: It's probably looping through the `childrenRect` - it's not isolated. In this small example there is no loop, because there are no layouts or grids that stretch with the content. But in your actual code there may be. Don't ask "what's wrong with qt", it's accurate when it comes to binding loops.

Comment: @JKSH - the binding loops are for other unrelated objects. They bind to the `main` properties only, and those are in no way dependent on the `debugrect` object.

Comment: @Velkan - I've been using QML since before it was even officially released, and my observations don't match yours. QML is OK for simple "by the book" things which is what you've been using it for, but as soon as you start doing complex and unorthodox things with it, you are faced by a swarm of bugs and poor design limitations. I have encountered 4 bugs in QML in the last 24 hours alone - object lifetime management, scene-graph visibility, qml compiler and bindings. It might be a good idea to get a good idea before praising Qt, through experience or just see how many critical bugs it has open..

Comment: @ddriver Then please provide an example which triggers the bug. It's hard for us to tell you what's wrong when we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ddriver, you are not reading what I am writing. Binding loops are easy, diagnostics are accurate. I'm not praising anything ("what's wrong with qt" - it's quote from your post, where you're trying to involve emotions), I'm just talking about the specific aspect.

Comment: @JKSH - this is not what this question is about, read the question carefully. The object does not influence anything nor is it referenced by anything, it is not a problem with the code.

Comment: It's referenced via `childrenRect` (not in the small example, but probably in your project).

Comment: @Velkan - no it is not, as it is not a child of the main item, that's the very reason it is wrapped in another item. It also doesn't have an id - it is piratically impossible to be referenced by anything.

Comment: Please, read what I'm writing. Repeating third time: it's not related here, so we don't reproduce the problem with this small example.

Comment: @Velkan - please, stop repeating, and even more so - please, cut the "I am competent" act, a few months ago you were asking basic questions, entirely clueless about qml, and now you pretend to know stuff which is years away of you, and pretend very poorly might I add. I know that you can't be of any help, so you might as well stop pretending.

Comment: @ddriver, discussing individual competence is the worst thing that one can do on StackOverflow. It slows down the resolving of the problem. So, I try to keep my comments as humble as possible.

Comment: @ddriver The presence of your `debugrect` affects the properties of your inner `Item`, and the properties of your inner `Item` affects the properties of your main `Item`. Therefore, the presence of your `debugrect` affects the properties of your main `Item`. It's not "completely isolated" as you insist. I'm guessing your binding loop(s) involve geometries... is that the case?

Comment: @JKSH - it "could" if there was the code for it. And there is no code for it. Be my guest, check if such a nesting results in any influence of the `debugrect` to the main item's `childrenRect`. The binding loop warning is for an element in a different source, that is instantiated by a loader, and has zero notion of, much less references to the rectangle in question.

Comment: @JKSH - if there was any connection debugrect -> main item, then THAT would cause a binding loop, as the debugrect is sized by the main item's children rect. There is no such binding loop because there is no such connection.

Comment: @ddriver You're right, `debugrect` doesn't actually affect the `childrenRect` of the main `Item`. I'm curious to find out the mechanism of what you've described too, but without an actual example there's no feasible way for me (or anyone else) to investigate. Won't you provide such an example?

Comment: @JKSH - oh wow, I am right, who would have thought :) I've tried reproducing it without exposing too much of the code since I am not allowed, but wasn't able to. I've debugged the code quite in detail though, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. My theory is that the presence of the `debugrect` somehow alters the order and structure of the chain of binding evaluations. The code if VERY complex, it took me months of pondering until I got it, it works flawlessly, but seems to hit a weak point and a potential bug in qtquick.

Comment: @ddriver _"My theory is that the presence of the `debugrect` somehow alters the order and structure of the chain of binding evaluations."_ -- That's certainly possible, since the order of evaluations is not defined.

Comment: @ddriver Does defining dimensions for your inner `Item` (`width: 0; height: 0`) make the warning disappear? Does setting constant dimensions for your `debugrect` make the warning appear? I'd also strip away other bits of your code one by one and see what else produces/suppresses the warnings. No guarantee that you'll find the root cause this way, but it might reveal other tidbits. Happy hunting!

Comment: @JKSH - no, it does not. Besides, those are all 0 by default. If the rect is not bound to the main childrenrect, the warnings are there. Also, it might be of some value to note that the debugrect is the ONLY reference to the main childrenRect. No other objects uses that internally, it is only used to size a flickable and adjust the vertical offset for negative space.

Comment: @ddriver So perhaps it's not the presence of the `debugrect`, but rather the fact that _something_ is bound to `main.childrenRect`. Anyway, without the ability to reproduce the bug, I doubt we can discover much so I'll take my leave. All the best.

Comment: @JKSH even without the debugrect the flickable's content size is still bound to the same properties, but it doesn't "do the magic"...